# Creating a link to another website and loading a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have just seen a website that can create a link to any website and display a modal when the link is clicked on someone else website. I was just curious if anyone knows how this is done?

Here's the test link that does this:

https://twitter.com/workladuk/status/955752813333766144

Comment: They are going to the new page and opening the modal onLoad of the page.

Comment: What specific question do you have? As it stands right know your question appears to be off-topic. Please have a look at [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you are talking about the `Demo Links`, they are on the same website but a different page with a JS executed. You can't open a model on another website you don't have control over

Comment: Here's the link that does it https://twitter.com/workladuk/status/955752813333766144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how this scheme works:

Notice that clicking on the link in the tweet mentioned in your comment (seen at https://twitter.com/workladuk/status/955752813333766144) doesn't actually take you to StackOverflow, even though it appears to point to this article.

It takes you to http://readr.me/vc-25, a totally different site. This is clear from the browser address bar.

By inspecting the HTML of that page using the browser developer tools, we can see that it actually is a totally different page containing an overlay with the signup form, and also an iframe containing the page the user was hoping to visit, giving the illusion that they're on the page and just need to close the popup to view it. Once they *do* close the popup, it actually makes a whole new HTTP request and redirects the user to the real page.

Interestingly, this was even more obvious given the example you used, because when going to the site with the signup form, the StackOverflow page displayed underneath it showed I was not signed in, even though I was signed in to SO in other tabs in the browser. This will be because running it in an iframe caused it to be run in a separate session, in which I was not signed in. This was a another big clue to show that I was not on the real Stackoverflow page.

So to be clear, it is absolutely *not* making a popup appear on another website, because that's impossible without hacking it. Instead it's actually creating another page containing the signup form, redirecting the user to that page and embedding the "real" page within that to create an illusion.

Comment: That would explain it I was getting so confused. So they are using a different website using a full width iframe and creating a model on it then, thats interesting... Thank you!